# Giving an exact description for $E_{R}:=\{\cos(z):\, R<|z|<\infty\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following homework problem:

> For each $R>0$ prove $$A(0,0,\infty)=\{e^{z}:\, z\in A(0,R,\infty)\}$$
>   and give an description of the set $$E_{R}:=\{\cos(z):\, z\in
>  A(0,R,\infty)\}$$

Where $$A(z_{0},r_{0},r_{1}):=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\, r_{0}<|z-z_{0}|<r_{1}\}$$

There is also a hint for the second part: if $\cos(z)=\omega$ for
some given $\omega\in\mathbb{C}$ then $e^{iz}$ must satisfy a certain
quadratic equation.

**What I did:**

I have proved the first part (which doesn't seem relevant for the
second part).

I have also used the hint: If 
$$
\cos(z)=\omega
$$

then 
$$
\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\omega
$$

hence 
$$
\frac{e^{iz}\cdot e^{iz}+e^{iz}\cdot e^{-iz}}{2}=\omega
$$

Denote $t=e^{iz}$. Then 
$$
t^{2}-2\omega t+1=0
$$

Hence 
$$
t_{1,2}=\frac{2\omega\pm\sqrt{4\omega^{2}-4}}{2}
$$
$$
t_{1,2}=\omega\pm\sqrt{\omega^{2}-1}
$$

I also noticed that $e^{-iz}$satisfies the same equation hence one
of $e^{iz},e^{-iz}$ is $t_{1}$ and the other is $t_{2}$.

I don't see how this help me since 
$$
t_{1}+t_{2}=2\omega
$$

hence
$$
\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\frac{t_{1}+t_{2}}{2}=\omega
$$

so this doesn't give me any new information.

This is where I am stuck, can someone please help me continue this
exercise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Let $f(z)=e^{iz},$ so $f(A(0,R,\infty))=A(0,0,\infty)$

Also, $g(z)=\frac12(z+\frac1z)$

Then $\cos z=\frac12(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})=(g\circ f)(z)$

Where foes $g$ map $A(0,0,\infty)?$

Well, generally $g$ maps the points $\{|z|>1\}$ conformally to $\mathbb C\setminus [-1,1]$

(See Bak-Newmann , Riemann Map chapter)
.

Also, the points of the circumference $|z|=1$ are mapped to the interval $[-1,1]$

Therefore, the image of $|z|\geq 1$ is the whole plane, which implies that the image of $A(0,0,\infty)$ is the whole plane.

**Solution 2** *(using the hint)*

You have proved that the image of $A(0,R,\infty) $ through $e^z$ is $A(0,0,\infty)$. The same holds if we replace $e^z$ with $e^{iz}$.

Now we will prove that the image of $A(0,R,\infty)$ through $\cos z$ is the whole plane.

Take a $w\in \mathbb C$. We need to prove that there exists $z\in A(0,R,\infty)$ such that $$\cos z=w\iff$$
$$e^{2iz}-2we^{iz}+1=0\iff $$$$t=e^{iz}, t^2-2wt+1=0$$

Therefore $t=\dfrac{2w\pm\sqrt{4w^2-4}}{2}=w\pm\sqrt{w^2-1}$

This proves already that for a given $w\in\mathbb C$, you can find a $t\in\mathbb C$ which is not zero, therefore it belongs in $A(0,0,\infty)$ . Now, obviously(from the first part of the exercise), for a given $t\in A(0,0,\infty)$ we can find a $z\in A(0,R,\infty)$ such that $e^{iz}=t$ and the proof has finished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please add some more details ? I still
don't understand how to use the hint, or how to find $g(A(0,0,\infty))$.